# I can no longer completely turn off the screen by decreasing the screen brightness to zero in 16.04

Tags: laptop, brightness, 16.04

Sorry if this is vague and not nearly as technical as most other questions here, but I'm a pretty new ubuntu convert. When I'm in hurry I've been turning off my screen just by holding fn and f8 to decrease my screen brightness to the lowest setting which used to completely turn the screen off, however after updating to 16.04 the lowest brigtness setting doesn't completely turn the screen off, is there any way to return the lowest brigtness setting to being a completely off state?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the command line

> sleep 0.2s && xset dpms force off

and press enter to have it display again.

you can write it into a script and put just have it launch from a desktop icon then you can click the icon and your screen will turn off then move your mouse/trackpad or press enter and your screen will display again.